# Regex to parse a string with an "=" separated string?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write regular expression in python. Let's say that I have a string

```
string = "alpha=23; beta=34; gamma=43"
```

I want to read this string and store the values of `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` in a database. How can I write a regex that would do that.

My guess is that i have to look for regex that checks for words followed by `=` sign. I wrote this:

```
matchObj = re.search( r'\w+(?==)', string, re.I)
```

This outputs `alpha` and stops?

1. Is this correct?
2. How can i read all the values?

Comment: Is the string always going to be "alpha=x; beta=x; gamma=x", or will the contents change?

Comment: i found the answer. i have to use findall instead of search.

Comment: girasquid, i am trying to read a file and each line in the file has alpha beta and gamma and they have diff values. so i am parsing one line at a time and reading the values and storing them in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1
Yes it is correct, search stops after the first match.

2
try `findall` instead of `search`

It returns a list.

```
re.findall( r'(\w+)=([^;]+)', string, re.I)
```

If you want to use split:

```
[re.split('=',s) for s in re.split(';',string)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have another issue. lets say the string is :String = "Alpha=34;Beta=C:4;C++:5;Gamma=Product". I was using this scheme to parse alpha beta gamma until i saw beta=C:4;C++:5;. I need to store the entire value of beta but using the reg-ex above, it will parse until the first occurrence of C:5; and stop. What would be a better reg-ex? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like:

```
s = "alpha=23; beta=34; gamma=43"
re.findall(r'([a-z]+)=(\d+)', s, re.I) or # (\w+) instead I guess
# [('alpha', '23'), ('beta', '34'), ('gamma', '43')]
```

**or without a regex (and possibly more useful)**

```
dict(i.split('=') for i in s.split(';'))
# {'alpha': '23', ' beta': '34', ' gamma': '43'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have another issue. lets say the string is :String = "Alpha=34;Beta=C:4;C++:5;Gamma=Product". I was using this scheme to parse alpha beta gamma until i saw beta=C:4;C++:5;. I need to store the entire value of beta such as "C:5;C++:5" so what would be a better reg-ex? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode it for your string:

```
alpha=(\d+); beta=(\d+); gamma=(\d+)
```

and then use `re.search` to get a `MatchObject` from which you can use groups 1–3 for the values of `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma`, respectively.

Another option is using `findall` with

```
(\w+)=(\d+)
```

where you can use groups 1 and 2 to get the identifier (`alpha`, ...) and the value.